# How to automatically switch to browser (which is minimized) from a different window (like Outlook or Explorer) upon receiving an alert on the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to automatically switch to browser (which is currently minimized) from a different window (like Outlook or Explorer) upon receiving an alert on a tab open in the minimized browser?

Looking for a solution using Javascript/Jquery.

I've tried the following but it does not work well at all times:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = setTimeout(function(){
            window.moveTo(500, 100);
            window.focus();
            alert('This is an alert');
            }, 5000);
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code it works when:

1. The minimize button on the browser is pressed to minimize the browser no matter how many tabs are present or which is the current active tab(it switches to the tab which generates the alert). (Chrome)

The above code fails when:

1. The minimize button on the browser is not pressed, instead ALT+TAB is used.
2. The minimize button on the browser is not pressed, instead an area of the screen outside the browser is clicked to minimize the browser window (Resized Browser Window).
3. For IE if multiple tabs are present, this code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

run the snippet

minimize the window

wait for seconds

```js
window.onload = setTimeout(function(){
            window.moveTo(0, 0);
            alert('This is an alert');
            window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
            window.focus();
            }, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the speedy response! 

However,

Your code works only when:

The minimize button on the browser is pressed to minimize the browser no matter how many tabs are present or which is the current active tab(it switches to the tab which generates the alert). (Chrome)

Your code fails when:

1. The minimize button on the browser is not pressed, instead ALT+TAB is used.
2. The minimize button on the browser is not pressed, instead an area of the screen outside the browser is clicked to minimize the browser window..
3. For IE if multiple tabs are present, this code fails.